# Dynamic URL generates dynamic content

Tags: urls

I am keen to understand how I might be able to do the following.

A list of products or *things* that might be a JSON data object or flat text file of *things*.

Let's say the list of things is:

```
twitter
facebook
instagram
```

I want to get a URL system that does this:

```
domain.com/advice-on-twitter
domain.com/advice-on-facebook
domain.com/advice-on-instagram
```

where `twitter` or `facebook` is the variable and I want `domain.com/advice-on-<random string>` to 404.

So I am seeing how to make a slug cause a template to load according to the template but I don't want to create a whole page in the backend with a slug.

So I want to make a dynamic page creation idea. The variable will be used with php to build content that is unique and render that per page.

I don't think there is much that can be done with `.htaccess` for this problem.

I want to get the string from the URL in PHP and therefore build my content.

I just need to get a page-template PHP file to load where I can start my PHP work.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you for any pointers as it is a loaded question to a degree.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually tackle it with the `.htaccess` file, using `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advice-on-(\[a-zA-z])$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://domain.com/customadvice?advice=$1 [L]
```

Note that the Regex in the parenthesis will be reused as `$1` in the `RewriteRule`.

You should then have a WordPress page on `/customadvice` and use the `$_GET` attribute from the page template for whatever use you need.

The path `/advice-on` should still give a 404.

Comment: Oh this could work, I will get testing thank you. My issue for not using htaccess was that it couldn't query my list of 'things' but I can do this check later and 404 if the url stripped doesn't match them...TY Marc-Antoine.

Comment: I am struggling to get a match for RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advice-on-(\[a-zA-z])$ will continue to see why....

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advice-on-[a-zA-Z]*$ [NC]

Comment: Ok So I can now get the variable in my page but creating a new page has changed the url..
I need the url to be 
domain.com/advice-on-twitter
vs
domain/customadvice/advice-on-twitter

and the issue is the redirect keeps recursing...because it matches always "advice-on-"

Comment: That is why I used parenthesis :) It will return only your advice string (i.e. twitter) in the `$1` variable, so it will not catch anymore in the `RewriteCond`. By the way, using the `*` symbol is gonna catch with ou without, so the URL `/advice-on-` would return true too. The right thing to use should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advice-on-(\[a-zA-z]+)$`, the plus symbol meaning one or more. Sorry for the inconvenience, missed it at first :)

Comment: "My issue for not using htaccess was that it couldn't query my list of 'things'" - if you have access to the server config, you can use a `RewriteMap`. It would be more efficient to match the URL in the `RewriteRule` pattern. No need for the `RewriteCond` in this instance.