# Load a template page based on part of slug in wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, slug

How can I load a particular template based on part of a slug ?

Say I have 3 urls that I want to load the same template for so I want to match based on the 'advice-on' Please note I don't want a single page for each creating in the backend. I want to generate the content dynamic.

This is more specific part of the wider question here- [Dynamic URL generates dynamic content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252289/dynamic-url-generates-dynamic-content)

---

domain.com/advice-on-twitter

domain.com/advice-on-facebook

domain.com/advice-on-instagram

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `template_include`, check the request URL for your search words and return a custom template.

Here is a primitive example:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {

    $template_map = [
        'advice-on' => 'advice',
        'links-' => 'link-collection',
    ];

    foreach ( $template_map as $find => $match ) 
    {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], $find ) )
            return get_template_directory() . "/$match.php"; 
    }

    return $template;
});
```

Comment: Thanks that's a great starting point for me to research. I see there are some good blogs around on this subject for more.